# Comparing Different File extension and Copying Files with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pdf, copy, compare, rtf

Scenario: *.pdf in Folder1 *.rtf in Folder 2, both folders have the same file name but with different extensions. Need to Compare the two folders and copy over only the *.rtf that equal => from Folder2 to Folder3.

Script:

```
    Compare-Object (Get-childitem $Folder1 -Recurse | foreach-object {$_.basename}) (Get-childitem $Folder2 -Recurse | foreach-object {$_.basename})     -Property RelativePath, Name, Length |
Sort RelativePath, Name, Length -desc | % {
if ($file -ne $_.RelativePath)
{ $_ }
$file = $_.RelativePath
} | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item ("$Folder2\" + $file) -Destination ("$Folder3\" + $file) -Force}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should actually have a question. I'm not sure where you got the property `RelativePath` from so I present this which should be fairly easy to follow. I could have made this into a one line command but, again, this is more readable.

```powershell
$Folder1 = "C:\temp\folder1"
$Folder2 = "C:\temp\folder2"
$Folder3 = "C:\temp\folder3"
$Folder1Contents = Get-childitem $Folder1 -Recurse -Include *.pdf
$Folder2Contents = Get-childitem $Folder2 -Recurse -Include *.rtf

Compare-Object $Folder1Contents $Folder2Contents -Property BaseName -PassThru | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | Move-Item -Destination $Folder3 -Force -WhatIf
```

Take the pdf files in `$Folder1` and compare them to the rtf files in `$Folder2`. If there is a .rtf file in `$Folder2` then it will be moved to `$Folder3`. `-Force` will overwrite and preexisting file in that directory so remove the `-WhatIf` once you are done testing.

Comment: Yea I forgot to ask the actual question. But you pegged it. Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Final result: I added a Transcript and if/elseif statement for logging. The double compare-object is just so that the compare results will show in the log. Thanks for your help Matt, you saved me hours of headache.

```
$Folder1 = "C:\temp\folder1"
$Folder2 = "C:\temp\folder2"
$Folder3 = "C:\temp\folder3"    
$log = "C:\logs\compare.log"

$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | out-null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"

$OutputFileLocation = "$log"
Start-Transcript -path $OutputFileLocation -append


$folder1contents = Get-childitem $folder1 -Recurse -Include *.pdf
$folder2contents = Get-childitem $folder1 -Recurse -Include *.rtf

$filecheck = "C:\temp\folder1\*.pdf"
$filepresent = Test-Path $filecheck

if ($filepresent -eq $false) 
{ 
Write-host "No Files To Compare" 
}

elseif  ($filepresent -eq $true) 
{
Compare-Object $folder1contents $folder2contents -Property BaseName -PassThru
Compare-Object $folder1contents $folder2contents -Property BaseName -PassThru | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | Copy-Item -Destination $folder3 -Force 

}

stop-transcript
```